# Python / Flask - Getting Programming Error

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to implement a simple flask login system to my project, but after a little time, the server crashes and I get this in my log:

```
2017-02-13 19:06:56,833 [      Thread-393][          pool][   ERROR] Exception during reset or similar
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/pool.py", line 687, in _finalize_fairy
    fairy._reset(pool)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/pool.py", line 829, in _reset
    pool._dialect.do_rollback(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 440, in do_rollback
    dbapi_connection.rollback()
ProgrammingError: SQLite objects created in a thread can only be used in that same thread.The object was created in thread id 140323586025216 and this is thread id 140323602810624
2017-02-13 19:06:56,834 [      Thread-393][          pool][   ERROR] Exception closing connection <sqlite3.Connection object at 0x7f9fc47ce200>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/pool.py", line 300, in _close_connection
    self._dialect.do_close(connection)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 446, in do_close
    dbapi_connection.close()
ProgrammingError: SQLite objects created in a thread can only be used in that same thread.The object was created in thread id 140323586025216 and this is thread id 140323602810624
2017-02-13 19:16:53,257 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine BEGIN (implicit)
2017-02-13 19:16:53,257 [     Thread-1179][           log][    INFO] BEGIN (implicit)
2017-02-13 19:16:53,258 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SELECT users.id AS users_id, users.username AS users_username, users.password AS users_password, users.disp AS users_disp
FROM users
WHERE users.username IN (?) AND users.password IN (?)
 LIMIT ? OFFSET ?
2017-02-13 19:16:53,258 [     Thread-1179][           log][    INFO] SELECT users.id AS users_id, users.username AS users_username, users.password AS users_password, users.disp AS users_disp
FROM users
WHERE users.username IN (?) AND users.password IN (?)
 LIMIT ? OFFSET ?
2017-02-13 19:16:53,258 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ('RicardoS', 'rvs92', 1, 0)
2017-02-13 19:16:53,258 [     Thread-1179][           log][    INFO] ('RicardoS', '1234', 1, 0)
2017-02-13 19:16:56,231 [     Thread-1176][          pool][   ERROR] Exception during reset or similar
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/pool.py", line 687, in _finalize_fairy
    fairy._reset(pool)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/pool.py", line 829, in _reset
    pool._dialect.do_rollback(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 440, in do_rollback
    dbapi_connection.rollback()
ProgrammingError: SQLite objects created in a thread can only be used in that same thread.The object was created in thread id 140323619596032 and this is thread id 140323611203328
2017-02-13 19:16:56,231 [     Thread-1176][          pool][   ERROR] Exception closing connection <sqlite3.Connection object at 0x7f9fc46fe858>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/pool.py", line 300, in _close_connection
    self._dialect.do_close(connection)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 446, in do_close
    dbapi_connection.close()
ProgrammingError: SQLite objects created in a thread can only be used in that same thread.The object was created in thread id 140323619596032 and this is thread id 140323611203328
2017-02-13 19:22:16,394 [      MainThread][     runserver][   ERROR] Uncaught exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "runserver.py", line 366, in <module>
    main()
  File "runserver.py", line 362, in main
    host=args.host, port=args.port, ssl_context=ssl_context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 843, in run
    run_simple(host, port, self, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 694, in run_simple
    inner()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 659, in inner
    srv.serve_forever()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 499, in serve_forever
    HTTPServer.serve_forever(self)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 233, in serve_forever
    self._handle_request_noblock()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 292, in _handle_request_noblock
    self.handle_error(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 290, in _handle_request_noblock
    self.process_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 607, in process_request
    t.start()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 736, in start
    _start_new_thread(self.__bootstrap, ())
error: can't start new thread
```

The part of the login is this one:

```
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///login.db', connect_args={'check_same_thread': False}, echo=True)
app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = os.urandom(12)

def do_login(self):


    POST_USERNAME = str(request.form['username'])
    POST_PASSWORD = str(request.form['password'])

    Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
    s = Session()
    query = s.query(User).filter(User.username.in_([POST_USERNAME]), User.password.in_([POST_PASSWORD]) )
    result = query.first()
    if result:
        session['logged_in'] = True
    else:
        flash('Password Errada!')
    return render_template('login.html')
```

Please help, I can't really solve this, I tried all the fixes I could find

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please post a Minimal Complete Verifiable example (which means posting the code that is relevant, the error, and what you expect to see instead inline, not as pastebin links)

Comment: Sorry about that, but all of that is relevant... :(

Comment: Then post it all... pastebin links (I believe) go away after some length of time, which makes your question less useful for people who might be having the same issue as you

Comment: It's done. Can you help me?

Comment: I haven't used sqlite/flask/sqlalchemy before, but doing some reading at http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/sqlite.html suggests that check_same_thread is now undocumented.  Can you move the call to create_engine into the do_login method? Also, there were some implications that this is only an issue when running flask in debug mode (as in production mode it tends to run everything in the same thread; the two threads in debug mode are so one thread can listen for changes to files and reload)... so trying to turn off debug mode probably wouldn't hurt as a quick check.

Comment: Check how you are establishing your connection to the database.  Take note of this error: `ProgrammingError: SQLite objects created in a thread can only be used in that same thread.The object was created in thread id 140323586025216 and this is thread id 140323602810624`